# What is the best-practice alternative for $scope.$watch?

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking for a best-practice solution to avoid using `$scope.$watch`, given the following use-case:

1) `directiveA` has the following isloated scope:

```
{ sharedModel : '=' }
```

2) for its own usage, `directiveA` needs to change its inner state variable named `modelA`, based on `sharedModel`.

3) `directiveB` uses `directiveA`, and binds `sharedModel` to `modelB` (its internal model).

```
<directive-a
  shared-model="vm.modelB" />
```

4) Whenever `modelB`/`sharedModel` changes, I would like `modelA` to be updated (remember, `modelA` data is only derived from`sharedModel`).

In order to accomplish #4, I could add `$scope.$watch` on `sharedModel`. **However, `$watch` is performance-expensive and not testable. Any best-practice reccomendations?**

#### EDIT:

for live code example [see jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomper/mggc611e/1/).
notice `$scope.$watch` on line #10 which I wish to replace.

Comment: what does "best-practice alternative" even mean? Why would an alternative to a framework feature be a best-practice? aside from that, it's not even really clear what the point is to having a "shared" variable that one piece of code can only one way bind and another is supposed to two way bind....

Comment: if you *really* want to achieve this strange behavior and avoid `$watch`, your only alternative is `$broadcast/$emit`, unless you write your own sub/pub mechanisms.

Comment: @Claies - though `$watch` is a 'framework feature', it's usage by the user is discouraged. Also, there is a need for two-way bind, but it's irrelevant for this use case (it's essentially the inverse process done by `directiveA` when processing `sharedModel`).

Comment: Can you post minimum code for your setup? there might be nice way to solve it without `$watch` or `$broadcast/$emit` (which is not proper way to do it at all).

Comment: @dfsq - sure, i've create a [jsfiddle][http://jsfiddle.net/tomper/mggc611e/1/]. thanks

Comment: @tomper The usage of `$watch` is not discouraged as far as I know. Angular uses it internally everywhere. Also as far as I know, there is not problem with testability of $watch, it's actually pretty easy to test it.

Comment: @Sulthan Usage of $watchers should be limited to the situations when there is no other way to do it without it. In many cases there is better way to do it without additional watcher.

Comment: @dfsq True, there is a performance penalty but that doesn't mean the use is actually discouraged. `$watch` is one of the core functions of angular.

Comment: @Sulthan my idea is that `$watch` is intended to be **mostly used by the framework**, and though user can easily use it, there are major disadvantages for doing so (see this post for example http://www.benlesh.com/2013/10/title.html). Same for goes for testing, you can manually invoke `$digest` to overcome `$watch` usage during unit tests, but unit testing should be functional and behavioral oriented, and the above is not within the normal flow.

Comment: @tomper In almost every controller test you will have to call `$digest` directly. Calling `$digest` is exactly the same as genering a key event to test an `onKeyUp` handler. If `$watch` were intended to be used only internally, it would be called `$$watch` and it woudn't be included in docs. That blog post is ***very*** subjective. In this case, `$watch` doesn't have to be used and that's good. Avoiding it altogether doesn't make sense though.

Comment: this question, now with code sample, still comes off as contempt for a framework feature rather than a practical request.  The code sample doesn't show any **practical** use for the problem request;  there is nothing demonstrating that performing math and storing the result in the variable is even necessary, and that math could be put directly in the expression where it would *internally* use `$watch` to update automatically.  Yet the question uses the phrase "best-practices" multiple times to emphasize it, as if there is a magic fix for this contrived problem.

Comment: in fact, the author in the article you posted to (an article written 2 years ago, against a completely different version of the framework), even stated a year later in a comment to that same article that "I've relaxed my opinions on this quite a bit.". I'd be interested to see more recent articles that can provide more evidence to support your opinion taken as hard fact here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case it's possible to do in without additional pricy watch. You can make use of old-good ES5 property [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), it's going to be very efficient. So instead of `$watch` try something like this:

```
Object.defineProperty($scope, 'modelA', {
    get() {
        return $scope.sharedModel * 10;
    }
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/mggc611e/2/

Comment: @dfq - your solution looks elegant, yet with a bit of a hack'ish scent :). I'll dive into it a bit, before accepting the answer. thanks

Comment: It's not "hackish", it's just pure javascript feature :)

Comment: I've tried it, but it seems that there's an efficiency issues. check out [my jsfiddle fork of your example](http://jsfiddle.net/tomper/2e28embg/), notice how for each `sharedModel` change, `modelA` get() is initiated 11 times (!). Now image the processing is a bit more complex than multiple by ten...

Comment: It's not going to be invoked 11 time, it's just you are changing `getCount` model inside of it making it unstable so digest runs 10 times to make sure model stabilizes (and it never does because you are incrementing it on each check). Here is the prove: http://jsfiddle.net/2e28embg/1/